# Error with org-fstree: Symbol's function definition is void: reduce

Tags: package, package-repositories, install, symbol-function

I want to use the package `org-fstree` [(MELPA Link)](https://melpa.org/#/org-fstree).

But in a file when I press `C-c C-c` at

```
#+BEGIN_FSTREE: ~/
```

I get the following **error**:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: reduce
```

I am not sure if I installed the package correctly (this is the first time I am using `MELPA`). So here is all the information that I feel may be relevant:

I added the `MELPA repository` by adding the following to my `~/.emacs`:

```
(when (>= emacs-major-version 24)
  (require 'package)
  (add-to-list
   'package-archives
   ;; '("melpa" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/") ; many packages won't show if using stable
   '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")
   t))
```

Then I restarted `Emacs`. I pressed `M-x list-packages` and pressed `i` at `org-fstree` to mark it for installation and pressed `x` to complete the installation.

I got the following warnings:

```
In org-fstree-extract-path-from-headline:
org-fstree.el:271:21:Warning: reference to free variable
    `org-fstree-heading-regexp'

In end of data:
org-fstree.el:311:1:Warning: the following functions are not known to be defined: reduce,
    org-columns-quit
```

Then I added the following lines to my `~/.emacs`:

```
;; org-fstree
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-fstree-20090723.819/")
(require 'org-fstree)
```

I got the above mentioned **error** after these steps.

Please advice me on what to do?

Comment: That package is very old. I think it would never make it into melpa nowadays. Try replacing `reduce` with `cl-reduce` in `org-fstree.el`. Furthermore, you should not need anything directly related to that package in your init file. Better add the comment line `;;;###autoload` before the two hooks at the end of the library and before the definitions of the hooked functions `org-fstree-show-entry-maybe` and `org-fstree-apply-maybe`. Byte-compile the library afterwards.

Comment: I notified the melpa maintainers about the problem: https://github.com/melpa/melpa/issues/5334

Comment: Note that adding those autoload cookies to the source isn't going to do anything unless the modified library is `package-install`'d (or equivalent).

Comment: @phils `(package-generate-autoloads "org-fstree" (current-directory))` called from within `org-fstree.el` (i.e., with `default-directory` set to the package directory) should do.

Comment: I am sorry for the late response. Thanks @Tobias: I think I understand the problem now. However I don't understand: 1. What will comment `;;;###autoload` do? 2. How should one byte-compile the library? 3. The point that @phils raised - what does that mean? 4. How does your comment to @phils solve the above problem?

And thanks for raising the issue on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `org-fstree` is very old.
The correction code below fixes several problems in the elisp file `org-fstree.el` of the package.
It also prepares the package for autoload. That means that the hooks and functions that work as entry points of the package are marked as auto-loaded. The package is only loaded on demand when one of those is really called.
All fixed problems are listed as comments in the correction code.

After installation of `org-fstree-20090723.819` you can
copy-paste the correction code into your `*scratch*` buffer
place point somewhere in the code and call `eval-defun` which is bound to <kbd>C-M-x</kbd>.

```el
(with-current-file "~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-fstree-20090723.819/org-fstree.el"
  ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
  ;; 1: Add ;;;###autoload at hooks and corresponding functions
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (let ((m (make-marker)))
    (while (progn (set-marker m (search-forward "(add-hook" nil t))
                  (marker-position m))
      (forward-line 0)
      (unless (looking-back ";;;###autoload\n")
        (insert ";;;###autoload\n"))
      (let* ((form (read (current-buffer)))
             (fun (nth 1 ;; function in (quote function)
                       (nth 2 form)))) ;; (quote function) in (add-hook (quote hook) (quote function))
        (find-function fun)
        (unless (looking-back ";;;###autoload\n")
          (insert ";;;###autoload\n"))
        (goto-char m))))
  ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
  ;; 2: replace `reduce' with `cl-reduce' to autoload the required cl package
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (re-search-forward "\\_<reduce\\_>" nil t)
    (replace-match "cl-reduce"))
  ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
  ;; 3: add `org-colview' required for the used function `org-columns-quit':
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (re-search-forward "^;; *Code:")
  (unless (looking-at "\n(require 'org-colview)")
    (insert "\n(require 'org-colview) ; needed for `org-columns-quit'"))
  ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
  ;; 4: Correct order of "defun org-fstree-extract-path-from-headline" and
  ;; "defconst org-fstree-heading-regexp".
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (let ((pos-defun (re-search-forward "(defun *org-fstree-extract-path-from-headline" nil t))
        (pos-defvar (re-search-forward "(defconst *org-fstree-heading-regexp" nil t))
        (pos-make-local (re-search-forward "make-variable-buffer-local *'org-fstree-heading-regexp" nil t)))
    (when (and pos-defun pos-defvar pos-make-local)
      (transpose-regions
       (progn (goto-char pos-defun)
              (forward-line 0)
              (point))
       (progn (forward-sexp)
              (point))
       (progn (goto-char pos-defvar)
              (forward-line 0)
              (point))
       (progn (goto-char pos-make-local)
              (up-list)
              (point)))))
  ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
  ;; 5: Installation tasks
  (write-region nil nil (buffer-file-name))
  (package-generate-autoloads "org-fstree" default-directory)
  (cl-assert (byte-compile-file (buffer-file-name))))
```

Note that there are some more minor problems reported by `byte-compile-file` for the corrected version of `org-fstree`.
Nevertheless, the corrected version of `org-fstree` is running in `emacs-version` 25.3.2 with `org-version` 9.1.6 and does more or less what it is supposed to do (as far as I see).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone gets here because they read [Emacs' Wiki: Eshell Prompt](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EshellPrompt) and wanted to try their "Summarising the path" prompt but got the same error as this question, you can fix it by replacing `reduce` with `cl-reduce` per @Tobias' comment. But why fix when you can copy?

```lisp
    (defun shortened-path (path max-len)
      "Return a modified version of `path', replacing some components
      with single characters starting from the left to try and get
      the path down to `max-len'"
      (let* ((components (split-string (abbreviate-file-name path) "/"))
        (len (+ (1- (length components)) (cl-reduce '+ components :key 'length)))
             (str "")) (while (and (> len max-len) (cdr components))
               (setq str (concat str (if (= 0 (length (car components)))  "/"
                 (string (elt (car components) 0) ?/)))
                   len (- len (1- (length (car components))))
                   components (cdr components)))
        (concat str (cl-reduce (lambda (a b) (concat a "/" b)) components))))
   (defun rjs-eshell-prompt-function ()
      (concat (shortened-path (eshell/pwd) 40)
              (if (= (user-uid) 0) " # " " $ ")))
   (setq eshell-prompt-function 'rjs-eshell-prompt-function)
```